# How to create concantrated layers?

Tags: deep-learning

How merge two layers or multiplyting without adding extra weights and another layer for CGAN?[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean adding two layers is merging then the following toy example  might help

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model

input_1 = Input(shape=(10))
input_2 = Input(shape=(10))

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128)(input_1)

y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128)(input_2)

# Merge two layers
z = x + y

out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128)(z)

model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=[out])

plot_model(model, to_file="model.png", show_shapes=True)
```

If we run the above code [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqAtw.png) will be the model architecture

I hope you found this toy example useful

Comment: actually i am trying to merge inputs in the gan to make it cgan, but i am not sure how to do it in just numpy

Comment: @javatex511 what exactly you mean by merge. Let's just say that x is of shape (128,) and y is of shape(128,) what should the output of merging x and y according to you. If you could tell me that. I think I can help

Comment: lets think  on cgan the input layer must be merged or multipled i think. i want to understand that part. because there is noise array and the labels array, will i merge it or multiple it before the generator?

Comment: @javatex511 I think we can use Concatenate layer so that when we merge x and y we get a shape of (256,) . Using numpy.stack(axis=-1) to achieve this

Comment: yes i did but appended 1x748 becameing 1x758 if i append 10x1 at the end of it how to make it fixed 64x748 and merge some labels ( 64x1 ) to noise input at the same time? is that possible ?@sai nikhit . .. input noise is 64x100 and i want to add labels onto it( 64x1 ) so they become 101, ithink its not cgans idea is it wrong?

Comment: What should be your expected output in terms of shape

Comment: when input is 64x100 concetrated output wiill be same shape output so 64x100 is that possbile after merge with labels(64X1)?

Comment: Can you point me to the paper or the article related to CGAN

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.1784.pdf 3rd page

''In the generator net, a noise prior z with dimensionality 100 was drawn from a uniform distribution
within the unit hypercube. Both z and y are mapped to hidden layers with Rectified Linear Unit
(ReLu) activation [4, 11], with layer sizes 200 and 1000 respectively, before both being mapped to
second, combined hidden ReLu layer of dimensionality 1200. We then have a final sigmoid unit
layer as our output for generating the 784-dimensional MNIST samples.

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-conditional-generative-adversarial-network-from-scratch/ please read this article. The architecture is well explained

Comment: read taht but its with keras , i am only stucked at point the input, how to make it combine with labels with numpy only

Comment: Use the shapes from that article and reshape them using numpy

Comment: n_nodes = 128 * 7 * 7
 model.add(Dense(n_nodes, input_dim=100))
 model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
 model.add(Reshape((7, 7, 128))) 
here is not clear, latent dim 100 inputs, but 128*7*7 outputs